# Why do I get a segmentation fault when I try to add a NUL terminator at the end of my string?

Tags: c

According to GDB, I get a segmentation fault when I try to assign `'\0'` to the last position in `request_line`. I can't use any memory on the heap (`alloc`, `malloc`, `calloc`) since this is a server implementation with some control handlers that can make it very hard to free space.

The size of `request_targetSize` is 24, which is correct.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char line[80] = "GET /index.html/search?q=cat HTTP/1.1";
   char *abs_path;
   char *str = NULL;
   char *request_target= NULL;
   char *query = NULL;


   //get request target
   char* startofRequest_target = strchr(line, '/');
   char* endofRequest_target = strchr(startofRequest_target, ' ');
   int request_targetSize = endofRequest_target - startofRequest_target;
   if (startofRequest_target != NULL && endofRequest_target != NULL) 
   {
       memcpy(request_target, startofRequest_target, request_targetSize);
       request_target[request_targetSize] = '\0';
   }
....
```

My guess is that it has to do with initializing the `request_target` array with `NULL`, but i get an error if I don't.

Why do I get this segmentation fault? Also, why do I sometimes need to assign my char* variables to `NULL` and sometimes not?

Comment: in gdb, `print request_target`

Comment: `char *request_target= NULL;` --> `char request_target[80];`

Comment: @inetknght If i do that i get `0x0` so NULL?

Comment: What is the max value of `request_targetSize` ?

Comment: @FelixRosén yes, typically `0x0 == NULL`. That suggests you're writing to a `NULL` pointer. It then begs the question, *why is `request_target` NULL?*; the answer to which I hope you can answer, being the original developer.

Comment: "when I try to assign `'\0'` to the last position in `request_line`" - huh? There is no variable called `request_line`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem as I see it is with

```
 memcpy(request_target, startofRequest_target, request_targetSize);
```

here, `request_target` is NULL and you're trying to write into it. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) hence the seg fault.

Instead of making `request_target` a pointer, consider using an array, like

```
char request_target[80]= {0};
```

Comment: That was what i was thinking as well, but if I dont do `char *request_target= NULL;` (say i instead do `char *request_target;`) then I get this error when I compile `error: variable 'request_target' is uninitialized when used`

Comment: @FelixRosén are you sure about that? Did you try the approach I mentioned?

Comment: @SuravGosh  Yes! It worked when I did `char request_target[80]= {0};` as you said. But tbh I'm not quite sure why. Why do i need to set it to `{0}` ? And why is a char array better then a pointer in this case? Thank you by the way!!

Comment: @FelixRosén `Why do i need to set it to ´{0}´ `  that's the initialization. `why is a char array better then a pointer in this case`, well, arrays are not pointers. In this case, an array would have already been allocated memory, but a pointer will not, unless allocated explicitly.

Comment: @FelixRosén and BTW, my name is Sourav, not Saurav, not Gosh, and definitely not  SuravGosh. Just saying. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize `request_target` with `NULL`, then before doing the `memcpy` you should allocate some memory for it (using `malloc` for example).

Edit: sorry, you've mentioned that you cannot use heap.